# Less CSS: driving includes through parameters

Tags: css, less

We have a LESS based stylesheet for which we would like to generate multiple color variations. We have defined an include file which contains the color variations (for now blue.less) and would like to generate and use green and red variations of this include file.

What we would like to do is to somehow parametrize less via the command line to include one of these specific color files. Does anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: Do you want to use only one of the variations at a time, or several on the same page?

Comment: I want to use one variation at a time. Basically I want to generate a master stylesheet for blue, green, red etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the color definitions into variables in a separate file, eg. `blue.less`:

```
@baseColor: #0000ff;  // blue
@accentColor: #00ffff;  // yellow?
```

then create a separate theme file, eg. `theme.less`, where you define how the base color should be changed to achieve your theme:

```
@link-color: @baseColor;
@link-hover-color: darken(@link-color, 15%);
@panel-header-highlight-color: darken(@accentColor, 15%);
...
```

then in a third file, e.g. `layout.less`, you define

```
a { 
    color: @link-color;
    &:hover {
        color: @link-hover-color;
    }
}
...
```

finally, create your `blue-master.less`:

```
@import "blue.less";
@import "theme.less";
@import "layout.less";
```

To create a `red-master.less` you should only need to write a color file and change one line in the above.

You *can* call the color-file `color.less`, and e.g. have a `blue/color.less` and a `red/color.less`, and use the `--include-path=..` parameter to `lessc` to make it generate different files based on command line parameters, but I would advise against it (it becomes much more arduous to work with in my experience).